# How to fit two bones in Three.js?

Tags: 3d, three.js, html5-canvas, blender

I have two models that where exported through blender on a JS format used by three.js framework. A body and a coat. Both of them have bones in different positions.

What I need is fit the coat on the body. However, when I set the body positions for the coat, the coat becames deformed like it doesn't rotate.
I have verified the documentation and other questions on the forum and I have found something about quaternon, but I didn't understand how to use it. The values of parameters are weird for me.

I would like to know if anyone knows how to solve this situation? I don't know if it is any property on Blender or I have to do something in my code.

Here is my code

```
var container, stats;

var camera, scene, renderer;

var finish = 0;
var parents = 0;

var sprites = {};
sprites.obj = [];

init();
animate();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.getElementById('game-screen').appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, 800/600, 1, 2000 );
    camera.position.z = 20;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xaaaaaa );
    scene.add( ambient );

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xaaaaaa );
    directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(800, 600);
    renderer.setClearColorHex(0x333F47, 1); //cor de fundo + alpha

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;

    container.appendChild(stats.domElement);


    // Add OrbitControls so that we can pan around with the mouse.
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( "models/personagem.js", function(geometry, materials){
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x55B663, skinning: true});
        var mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, material);
        sprites.obj[0] = mesh;
        scene.add(mesh);

        finish++;
    });

    loader.load( "models/paleto.js", function(geometry, materials){
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFF00FF, skinning: true});
        var mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, material);
        sprites.obj[1] = mesh;
        scene.add(mesh);

        finish++;
    });

    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
}


function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    if(finish == 2 && sprites.obj[0] && sprites.obj[1]) {
        finish = 0;

        scene.updateMatrixWorld();

        for(i in sprites.obj[0].bones) {
            for(j in sprites.obj[1].bones) {
                if(sprites.obj[0].bones[i].name != sprites.obj[1].bones[j].name)
                    continue;

                parents = 0;

                sprites.obj[1].bones[j].position.x = sprites.obj[0].bones[i].position.x;
                sprites.obj[1].bones[j].position.y = sprites.obj[0].bones[i].position.y;
                sprites.obj[1].bones[j].position.z = sprites.obj[0].bones[i].position.z;
            }

        }

        sprites.obj[1].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        sprites.obj[1].geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
    }

    render();
    controls.update();
    stats.update();
}

function render() {

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Here is my models

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ho1inpfab1s36xq/personagem.js
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uuk0uprnqw61tac/paleto.js

Regards
Luiz